# Quickly select all "other" modifications during merge

Tags: git, rebase

Let's say one is running `git pull --rebase` from remote branch, that results in lots of conflicts in the files being merged to.

Is there a quick way without tedious file editing (some git command?) that would just take all alternatives from the remote branch and ignore alternatives from the local branch for the given file?

Answer (score 0):

Not really, no, and that's unwise in general.  You can write yourself a script to do it, though:

- When rebase stops with conflicts, the "ours" and "theirs" versions are left *in the index / staging area*, along with Git's attempt at resolving the conflicts in your working tree.
- So, "all" you need to do is *extract* the `--theirs` version of each such file, which you can do with `git restore` (or the old `git checkout` if your Git predates Git 2.23).
- You can find such files *in* the index with `git ls-files --stage`.

Write yourself a script that runs `git ls-files --stage`, finds files that exist in the three nonzero staging slots, and uses `git restore` and `git add` to replace the working tree copy with the slot-3 (`--theirs`) version of each file.

Note that this destroys any work you have done yourself in those files, even when it did not conflict; it thus may produce completely bogus mixes of files (since some files you worked on may not have any conflicts and hence may bring their changes in).

(If you meant "does the merge, but uses `-X theirs`", then yes: just pass `-X theirs`.  This is less drastic, but still not always wise.  It's also pretty obvious from the documentation, which is why I assumed you did not mean this.)